# How to get the bit removed from the bitwise right shift in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, shift

I have a int number And I have to shift it to the right a couple of times.

```
x   = 27 = 11011
x>>1= 13 = 1101
x>>2=  6 = 110
x>>3=  3 = 11
```

I would like to get the value bit value that has been removed. I would have to get: 1, 1, 0

How can I get the removed value

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Can you just make x & 1 every time before shift it right?

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, what are you doing with those bits after you've determined them? If you're combining them again in some way, there might be a more efficient way of doing the entire operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For least significant bit you can use `x & 1` before each shifting. If you want to get a custom bit at any time without changing the value, you can use below method.

```
    private static int GetNthBit(int x, int n)
    {
        return (x >> n) & 1;
    }
```

Comment: nice, but why not just `(x >> n) & 1`?

Comment: You are right! That was the first came up to my mind, I updated (:

Answer (score 7):

`(x & 1)` gives you the value of the least significant bit. You should calculate it *before* you shift.

Answer (score 1):

Just test the first bit before removing it

```
int b = x & 1;
```

[See MSDN reference on & operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)